# SQL Server 2008 column prefix error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have this working properly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLiveStream(@UserName NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN (
    SELECT DISTINCT l.* 
      FROM StreamView l
      JOIN Friendships f ON f.Sender = @UserName OR f.Recipient = @UserName 
     WHERE l.Sender <> @UserName 
       AND l.Recipient <> @UserName 
       AND (   l.Sender = f.Recipient 
            OR l.Sender = f.Sender 
            OR l.Recipient = f.Sender 
            OR l.Recipient = f.Recipient) 

  )
GO
```

But when trying to do the following query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS RowNumber, 
       * 
  FROM dbo.GetLiveStream('jason') 
  WHERE RowNumber >= 0
  AND RowNumber < 0+ 10;
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'RowNumber'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'RowNumber'.

Note that specifying `l.*` returns this error:

> Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   The column prefix 'l' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

GetLiveStream is a function:

```
RETURN (
    SELECT DISTINCT l.* 
      FROM StreamView l
      JOIN Friendships f ON f.Sender = @UserName OR f.Recipient = @UserName 
     WHERE l.Sender <> @UserName 
       AND l.Recipient <> @UserName 
       AND (   l.Sender = f.Recipient 
            OR l.Sender = f.Sender 
            OR l.Recipient = f.Sender 
            OR l.Recipient = f.Recipient) AND f.IsPending = 0

  )
```

How can this be resolved? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference an alias in the `WHERE` clause.  Do this:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS RowNumber, 
           * 
      FROM dbo.GetLiveStream('jason') 
) a
  WHERE RowNumber >= 0
  AND RowNumber < 0+ 10;
```

As for your `l.*` error, that's because that alias is local to the function and its query definition and can't be referenced outside of it.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `*` in a stored procedure or function because it gets compiled into a list of columns, which can change over time and thus break the compiled code. SQL Server doesn't warn you when that happens.

Comment: Whereas this is prudent and good advice, it doesn't address the immediate problems the OP is having.